# css3 transitions in opera causes border-bottom not to show up randomly

Tags: css, opera, transition

I created css3 menu. Link is here http://test.partnuz.hekko.pl/eliticon/1032px/ . Although it correctly renders the transition in opera, it sometimes shows the bottom border and sometimes not. Any solution ?

Link to css code is http://test.partnuz.hekko.pl/eliticon/1032px/css/dropdown.css

Comment: You need to add more information. What is the CSS you are using? Under what circumstances does the bottom border not show?

Comment: I suppose we are looking at your menu? The border is always showing, but when you look closely the height of the menu element isn't consistent. Sometimes it moves up one pixel too much. Therefor I'd say it is more of a javascript issue.